# Programmatically start a workflow AS A SPECIFIC USER

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Starting a workflow programmatically is not an issue anymore thanks to lots of posts and threads about it. Definitely the answer is to use the below method with appropriate parameters.

```
SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(...)
```

Every time we use the above method, workflow runs on the item without any problem. Going to the workflow history page (by clicking on the workflow status in the list view), it can be seen that the workflow initiator is set to system account (Initiator:    System Account). Now, the question is can you use the above method to start a workflow and do it as a specific user?

Comment: You have to impersonate the user credentials: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433494/Impersonation-in-SharePoint-2010

Answer (score 1):

You have to impersonate the user credentials:

By using a Token:

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUserToken token = oWeb.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINTSYSTEM"].UserToken;

using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(oWeb.Site.ID, token))
 {
    using (SPWeb elevatedweb = site.OpenWeb())
     {
      // your code
     }
 }
```

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/

or by using Win32 impersonation:
http://wayneye.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/a-complete-impersonation-demo-in-c-net/

Comment: Thanks cansik for mentioning that interesting article. I tested what you said and it works. However, in my case the user actually does not have permission to start workflow on the item. I want to run the workflow as the administrator but set the initiator field to that user. I have done a similar thing with adding and updating list items when users does not have the required permission. I add them through elevated privileges and then set "Author" and/or "Editor" fields. What I really need is to start the workflow as admin, but somehow set the initiator to a specific user.

Comment: btw, in your code, in the impersonation block you have to say elevatedWeb=elevatedSite.OpenWeb() instead of elevatedWeb=site.OpenWeb()